# Prompt to call a method in a function failing to work

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to use a prompt to call a predefined method to run a calculation.  When I try to convert the prompt response into the already defined method it fails (false) so it ends up not calculating the correct answer in all cases.  Here is all my code for context:

```
function PerishableFood(name,lastBuyDate,quantity, expirationDate) {
this.item = name;
this.buyDate = lastBuyDate;
this.quantity = quantity;  
this.expireDate = expirationDate;

}


var milk = new PerishableFood('1% Milk','07/05/2017',1, '07/14/2017');
var eggs = new PerishableFood('Cage Free Organic Dozen Eggs', '07/05/2017',2,'07/07/2017');
var bread = new PerishableFood('Honey Wheat Naures Own', '07/05/2017',1,'07/17/2017');
var butter = new PerishableFood('Land O Lakes Real Butter', '07/05/2017',2,'8/30/2017');
```

Then I calculate a current date which I can later use for determining if something is expired or not.  Here is that part:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10) {
dd = '0'+dd
} 
if(mm<10) {
mm = '0'+mm
} 
today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
```

So at this point I now want to actually use all of the above code to actually do something.  I initially had it so that I manually changed things and it calculated properly.  But I want to use a prompt to allow me to select which item that I want to calculate if it is expired or not.  Here is that code which is my actual question and where everything is failing...

```
 var userChoice = prompt("Which would you like the expiration date for?   Type: milk, eggs, bread or butter.");
 var userChoiceSelected = userChoice + "." + "expireDate";

 var expired = function(PerishableFood) {

 if(userChoiceSelected<=today) {
//  this is what I did before the above which worked but was very manual to change out every time: if(eggs.expireDate<=today) {
  return "The " + userChoice + " expired.  You need to buy more.";
    }
  else {
      return "You do not need to buy more " + userChoice + ".";
      }
     }
   console.log(expired(PerishableFood));
```

To see if my method is not working I wrote the following:

```
console.log(userChoiceSelected === milk.expireDate);
```

Which when I run this it is false.  Which tells me that trying to call userChoiceSelected will not do the same as when I just manually entered (see commented out code) //if(eggs.expireDate<=today) because this was eggs.expireDate but apparently userChoiceSelected is not becoming eggs.expireDate which explains why it fails but I have no idea why that is happening or how to fix it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the right way. Your variable "userChoiceSelected" is a String, for example, "milk.expiredDate", not a method. You should put all your instances into a Javascript Object like this:

```
var myobjects = {
  milk: new PerishableFood('1% Milk','07/05/2017',1, '07/14/2017'),
  eggs: new PerishableFood('Cage Free Organic Dozen Eggs', '07/05/2017',2,'07/07/2017'),
  bread: new PerishableFood('Honey Wheat Naures Own', '07/05/2017',1,'07/17/2017'),
  butter: new PerishableFood('Land O Lakes Real Butter', '07/05/2017',2,'8/30/2017')
};
```

Then you'll be able to call the userChoice like this:

```
userChoiceSelected = myobjetcs[userChoice].expiredDate;
```

## EDIT (just ideas)

Also you can evolve it by adding that method expired directly to your class. So you'll call `myobjects['milk'].isExpired()`, for example.